# Custome react hooks with fetching is loop because hooks recive a argument from component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The component and the hooks:

```
// FulfillmentOrders.js
export default function FulfillmentOrders (props) {
  const { list, fetchList } = useFetchSOList(1)
  return (...)
}

// useFetchSOList.js
export default status => {
  const initialSearch = {
    status,
    current: 1,
    pageSize: 10,
    total: 0,
  }
  const [list, setList] = useState()
  const fetchList = useCallback((search = {}) => {
    const defaultSearch = search.reset ? initialSearch : search
    const {
      current,
      pageSize,
      status,
    } = defaultSearch
    axios.post().then().catch().finally()
 }, [initialSearch]}
}
```

Then the fetching is looping infinity, I try to remove the `status` property from `initialSearch`, it's still looping.
I'm wondering why, it's confuse me.

Answer (score 0):

After asked the question, I find I know the key of this problem, because the current `initialSearch` is always diffent with pre value , so use `useMemo` to cache the value.

```
const getInitialSearch = status => ({
  status,
  current: 1,
  pageSize: 10,
  total: 0,
})

// useFetchSOList.js
export default status => {
 const initialSearch = useMemo(() => getInitialSearch(status), [status])
  const [list, setList] = useState()
  const fetchList = useCallback((search = {}) => {
    const defaultSearch = search.reset ? initialSearch : search
    const {
      current,
      pageSize,
      status,
    } = defaultSearch
    axios.post().then().catch().finally()
 }, [initialSearch]}
}
```